# How to compare 2 columns values and get the count of pairs of matches in python

Tags: python, pandas

This is the header of the DataFrame

```
user_id       timestamp                group         landing_page                 converted

0   851104  2017-01-21 22:11:48.556739    control         old_page                       0
1   804228  2017-01-12 08:01:45.159739    control         old_page                       0
2   661590  2017-01-11 16:55:06.154213    treatment       new_page                       0
3   853541  2017-01-08 18:28:03.143765    treatment       new_page                       0
4   864975  2017-01-21 01:52:26.210827    control         old_page                       1
```

and the question for me is "what is The number of times the new_page and treatment don't match?
and I used the following:

```
df[(df["group"]!= "treatment") & (df["landing_page"]=="new_page")]
df[(df["group"]== "treatment") & (df["landing_page"]!="new_page")]
```

but it counts them separately is there a better way to do it? or how to get the count of non-matched pairs?

Comment: As an output do you want the count or the dataframe?

Comment: I need only the count, of non-matched pairs

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
df.groupby(['group','landing_page'])['user_id'].count()
```

which will give you:

```
group      landing_page
control    old_page        3
treatment  new_page        2
```

And if you want the number directly, you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['group','landing_page'])['user_id'].count()).sum()
```

which prints:

```
user_id    5
```

Comment: did you see the edited answer? isn't 5 (the sum of the two) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In order to easily get the non-matched pairs, I would create a new column that maps "old_page" onto "control" and "new_page" onto "treatment"

```
df['landing_page_group'] = df.landing_page.map({'old_page': 'control', 'new_page': 'treatment'})
```

You can filter on just the rows that don't match and get the number of rows

```
len(df.loc[df.group != df.landing_page_group])
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i wanted exactly and sorry if my question wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical xor `^` to check if the conditions are opposing:

```
df[(df["group"] == "treatment") ^ (df["landing_page"] =="new_page")]
```

Comment: the "^" sign is interesting, what does it mean in this position?

Comment: This is used as a logical XOR. The [XOR operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) is true if the two inputs are different.